# How do I find the last entry in a table, by date

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, max

My query keeps returning the last date for ONRENT and CLOSED for the same piece of equipment when I add the column "AVAILABILITY".  I only want the last entry for each piece of equipment.

Here is my query:

```
select      max([No_]), [Start Date], [Availability Status]
from        [Rental Line]
group by    [No_], [Start Date], [Availability Status]
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you're using. SQL syntax varies from implementation to implementation.

Comment: Most difficult query to read with such field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want only the last availability status for each piece of equipment defined by No_, where "last" would be defined by the latest start date. If so, this should work:

Try this:

```
select      RL.[No_], RL.[Start Date], RL.[Availability Status]
from        [Rental Line] RL
join
(
    select
        No_,
        MAX([Start Date]) AS [LastStartDate]
    from [Rental Line] RL1
    group by No_
) X on RL.No_ = X.No_ AND RL.[Start Date] = X.[LastStartDate]
```

Comment: mayabelle, You nailed it.  Thanks so much.  I relatively new to SQL and am learning exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

```
select      max([No_]), [Start Date], [Availability Status]
from        [Rental Line]
group by    [No_], [Start Date], [Availability Status]
order by    [AVAILABILITY] DESC
```

Comment: Including the column that is part of an aggregate (`max()`) into the `group by` does not make any sense.

Comment: Thanks globula_alba but this is still giving me multiple availability status's for each piece of equipment.  For instance a single piece of equipment may have been rented 10 times in the past so the latest entry by date will show "ONRENT" or "CLOSED" depending on whether it is still on rent or not.

Comment: select      max([No_]), [Start Date], [Availability Status]
from        [Rental Line]
group by    [No_], [Start Date], [Availability Status]
order by    [AVAILABILITY] DESC LIMIT 1